# Assembly.LoadFrom is not loading DLL from folder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I built an app that needs access to three DLL's for an optional feature. 
Since it's optional, I don't ship those 3 DLL's and let the user select if he wants or not to have it.
But since I'm actually using the DLL in code, I need to reference them (via nuget).

The problem is that if those 3 DLL's are stored in a folder different than where the main executable is located, the app fails to access them.

> SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll
>   SharpDX.dll
>   SharpDX.DXGI.dll

I already tried to manually call `Assembly.LoadFrom(path)` without success.
The strange part is that the app fails to load one of them:

[image: Load]

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (27/02/2020 @ 10:51:36) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = SharpDX.DXGI, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyApp.exe
Calling assembly : MyApp, Version=2.21.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: SharpDX.DXGI, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI/SharpDX.DXGI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI/SharpDX.DXGI.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.



*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (27/02/2020 @ 10:51:36) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = SharpDX.DXGI, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyApp.exe
Calling assembly : MyApp, Version=2.21.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: SharpDX.DXGI, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4dcf0f35e5521f1
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI/SharpDX.DXGI.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp/SharpDX.DXGI/SharpDX.DXGI.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

The code that tried to load the three DLL's is this and it runs right before any call or reference to the SharpDX library appears, I debugged and it executes those lines normally:

```
public static void LoadSharpDx()
{
    var realPath = UserSettings.All.SharpDxLocationFolder ?? "";

    //In order to get the correct location, I need to combine the current base directory with the relative path.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserSettings.All.SharpDxLocationFolder) && !Path.IsPathRooted(UserSettings.All.SharpDxLocationFolder))
        realPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, UserSettings.All.SharpDxLocationFolder.Replace(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(realPath) || realPath == ".")
        return;

    //The realPath is C:\Users\nicke\Desktop\Dll  
    //So, it's correct.

    Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(realPath, "SharpDX.dll"));
    Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(realPath, "SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll"));
    Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(realPath, "SharpDX.DXGI.dll"));

    //Throws a different error.
    //Assembly.Load(Path.Combine(realPath, "SharpDX.dll"));
    //Assembly.Load(Path.Combine(realPath, "SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll"));
    //Assembly.Load(Path.Combine(realPath, "SharpDX.DXGI.dll"));
}
```

When analyzing ProcMon, I can see that the app is able to find and load the DLL inside the folder.

[image: ProcMon]

**So, what's going on?**

Why can't it load the SharpDX.DXGI library?

Comment: does sharpdx require/have 32/64 bit versions?

Comment: As far as I know, it does not.

Comment: Open the csproj with notepad and see if the location is correct.  I often edit csproj file to replace hard coded path names with relative paths like ../../filename

Comment: @jdweng I'm trying to load the DLL's dynamically.

Comment: I was able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I interpreted wrong what `Assembly.LoadFrom()` was doing.

In the end, I just had to use the `CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event:

```
private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        var assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',').First();

        if (!assemblyName.StartsWith("SharpDX"))
            return null;

        //Simply converts relative paths to full paths in order to
        //prevent getting the wrong path when the app is loaded from a
        //link or "Open with..." commands.
        var path = Other.AdjustPath(UserSettings.All.SharpDxLocationFolder ?? "");

        return Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, $"{assemblyName}.dll"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogWriter.Log(e, "Error loading assemblies");
        return null;
    }
}
```